# Building Android Apps on Ubuntu

Tags: android

I want to learn to build apps on Ubuntu, so after doing some resarch, I found out I need to install Eclipse.

The problem I have now is which one:

There's SO many on:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

or I should install:

> sudo aptitude search eclipse p   eclipse
>   - Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE                                                      p   eclipse-cdt
>   - C/C++ Development Tools for Eclipse                                                        p   eclipse-cdt-jni
>   - C/C++ Development Tools for Eclipse (JNI)                                                  p   eclipse-egit
>   - Eclipse Team provider for the Git version control system                                   p   eclipse-emf
>   - Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)                                                           p   eclipse-emf-examples
>   - Eclipse EMF/XSD examples                                                                   p   eclipse-emf-sdk
>   - Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) - (Source/Documentation)                                  p   eclipse-jdt
>   - Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT)                                                       p   eclipse-jgit
>   - Java implementation of GIT for Eclipse                                                     p   eclipse-pde
>   - Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)                                              p   eclipse-platform
>   - Eclipse platform without development plug-ins                                              p   eclipse-platform-data
>   - Eclipse platform without development plug-ins (data)                                       p   eclipse-rcp
>   - Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP)                                                         p   eclipse-rse
>   - Eclipse Remote System Explorer (RSE)                                                       p   eclipse-xsd
>   - XML Schema Definition (XSD) for Eclipse                                                    p   eclipse-xsd-sdk
>   - XML Schema Definition (XSD) for Eclipse - (Source/Documentation)                           p   libcommons-jci-eclipse-java
>   - common Java interface for various compilers - Eclipse JDT                                  p   libeclipselink-java
>   - Eclipse Persistence Services Project                                                       p   libeclipselink-java-doc
>   - Documentation for libeclipselink-java                                                      p   redeclipse
>   - multiplayer FPS game based on Cube2                                                        p   redeclipse-data
>   - data for the Red Eclipse FPS game                                                          p   redeclipse-dbg
>   - debug symbols for the Red Eclipse FPS game                                                 p   redeclipse-server
>   - server for the Red Eclipse FPS game                                                        p   redeclipse-server-dbg
>   - debug symbols for the Red Eclipse dedicated server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download `eclipse kepler standard package 4.3.1` from  [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-431/keplersr1).It was the latest version of eclipse.
- Eclipse was the Best IDE for Android app development.Download `32 or 64 bit version` of kepler package according to your system configuration.